# Loose control from constructor

Tags: java, class, exception, double

I am trying to call a custom catch expression

```
String value1 = side1_tb.getText();
String value2 = side2_tb.getText();
String value3 = side3_tb.getText();
try
{
    result_lbl.setText(
        actual_triangle.Triangle(
            Double.parseDouble(value1),
            Double.parseDouble(value2),
            Double.parseDouble(value3)));
}
catch (NumberFormatException exe)
{

}
```

So from the above code you can see that there are three textboxes values are being assigned to a string variables and then I implemented a try and catch method with 'Numberformatexception' but in the place of 'Numberformatexception' I want to implement a custom exception and this exception will be declared in another class lets call this class EXCEPTIONclass.java and in here I want to create an exception if String values are not being able to parse to double values, which I am trying to achieve in the above code.

Not really sure how to extend the exception class and then declare a new exception.

Comment: Please use the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), so let's not call it EXCEPTIONclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
public class MyCustomException extends Exception
{
    // To keep compiler happy about Exception being serializable.
    // Note: This should carry meaningful value when these exceptions are going 
    // to be serialized
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    public MyCustomException(String message, Throwable t)
    {
        super(message, t);
    }

    // Other constructors of interest from the super classes.
}
```

In your catch block, you would wrap the NumberFormatException as follows:

```
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
    throw new MyCustomException("<Your message>", nfe);
}
```

Comment: small problem, before I asked this question I have created your MyCustomException class already and in that a method to do some other check. And this method I called from another class, it was working fine till I created a constructor as you suggested and now I am getting an error at the place where I am calling the other method in the MyCustomException , tks but other than that this works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just create your exception class deriving it from Throwable ( for checked exception )  or RuntimeException ( if you like it to be unchecked )   and  throw it from your catch clause.